# Minitest: No more expects available

Tags: ruby, minitest

I use minitest to write the tests for my web project.
I have a mock object with 3 methods mocked. The object represents a database entity (hanami model) with several properties. Now, if I call the "getter" for one property more than once, I get a MockExpectationError: No more expects available for property.
How can I handle this without creating a variable to save the returned data?
Here is how I set this method up:

```
user_mock = Minitest::Mock.new
user_mock.expect :is_allowed?, true, [String, String]
user_mock.expect :ad_login, 'somestring'
user_mock.expect :id, 2
```

Comment: It seems that you're setting an expectation for method to be called exactly once. You should set it up for multiple calls. "exactly N times" or "at least once" (whatever fits your test better). Not sure how it's done in minitest (I am rspec guy)

Comment: I have searched the Minitest docu but I just can't find how to set the method up to be called multiple times. And it seams that the default is 1...

Comment: Well, maybe you should use a better testing framework :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a few more `expects` to the function you are calling more than once.

Say it is

```
user_mock.expect :is_allowed?, true, [String, String]
```

You can add a few more expects and you can even change the return value or expected parameters in each call.
So if you want to call it 3 times just add 2 more so you will end up with:

```
user_mock = Minitest::Mock.new
user_mock.expect :is_allowed?, true, [String, String]
user_mock.expect :is_allowed?, false, [String, String]
user_mock.expect :is_allowed?, true, [String, String]
user_mock.expect :ad_login, 'somestring'
user_mock.expect :id, 2
```

the values will be returned in the same order you have defined them.

Comment: Is there a way to make `expect` available more than once with a single call?